# Need Help on String Formatting

Tags: python, string, file

I've written this program in Python 3 that takes a CSV file that finds the min and max death rates for particular states.

I've basically finished the program and it outputs correctly in the shell, but I have a problem:

1. Different states have different lengths of characters in their names and the spacing does come out correctly, how do I use string formatting to make the strings space evenly regardless of the number of characters printed?

Here is what I have:

```
print ("\n", "Indicator                       |", "Min                   ",
       "        | Max     ")
print ("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
```

This is the output:

[image]

It works well for "Minnesota" but for "District of Columbia" it doesn't format evenly.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450472/how-to-format-print-to-fixed-width-of-strings

Comment: Use [the logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use string formatting as described here: http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/string.html

e.g.:

```
print('{:20} | {:20} {:5.2f} | {:20} {:5.2f}'.format(title, states[statemin], minimum, states[statemax], maximum))
```

Replace 20 with the longest string that will ever occur.

Note that I am assuming that minimum and maximum are floats, if they are strings, you cannot use '{:x.yf}' notation and you could just use {:6} or something like that instead.

`{:20}` means that `20` characters of space is used for the string, even if it is shorter (it does not truncate when longer). `{:5.2f}` means that `5` spaces are used for the float, of which `2` are after the decimal point.

Comment: So :20 is the character spacing I assume? What does the .2f do?

Comment: What does :20 do exactly? Doesn't let the strings go beyond 20 characters?