# columns and rows in python

Tags: rows, multiple-columns, python-3.3

How would I add columns and rows to this program? I am trying to tidy it up.

```
n = 5

rate = 0.05

for n in range(0, 3):

    principal = 10000

    for n in range (0,6):

        simple = principal * (1 + rate * n)

        compound = principal * (1 + rate)**n

        ratea = rate * 100

        ratea = int(ratea)

        principal = int(principal)

        print((ratea),"% $",principal," $","{:.2f}".format(simple)," $","{:.2f}".format(compound))

        principal = principal + 1000

    rate = rate + 0.05
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add columns and rows"?

Comment: I meant just tidy it up in straight lines when I run the program. So the $ signs match up and everything else.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8450472/2954547