# How to get key and value in well format and n/a values at the end in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Sort the data in ascending order and the keys which are not present need to be printed in the last.

Please suggest a solution and also suggest if any modifications is required.

**Input.txt-**

```
3=1388|4=1388|5=M|8=157.75|9=88929|1021=1500|854=n|388=157.75|394=157.75|474=157.75|1584=88929|444=20160713|459=93000546718000|461=7|55=93000552181000|22=89020|400=157.75|361=0.73|981=0|16=1468416600.6006|18=1468416600.6006|362=0.46
3=1388|4=1388|5=M|8=157.73|9=100|1021=0|854=p|394=157.73|474=157.749977558|1584=89029|444=20160713|459=93001362639104|461=26142|55=93001362849000|22=89120|361=0.71|981=0|16=1468416601.372|18=1468416601.372|362=0.45
```

**Program-Code-**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from operator import itemgetter   
df = pd.read_csv("C:\",index_col=None, names=['text'])
s = df.text.str.split('|')
ds =[dict(w.split('=',1 ) for w in x) for x in s]
p = pd.DataFrame.from_records(ds)
p1 = p.replace(np.nan,'n/a', regex=True)
st = p1.stack(level=0,dropna=False)
dfs = [g for i, g in st.groupby(level=0)]
dfs_length = len(dfs)
i = 0
while i < len(dfs):    
    print '\nindex[%d]'%i
    for (_,k),v in dfs[i].iteritems():
        print k,'\t',v
    i = i + 1
```

**OUTPUT (I got):**

```
index[0]
1021      1500      
1584      88929     
16        1468416600.6006
18        1468416600.6006
22        89020     
3         1388      
361       0.73      
362       0.46     
388       157.75    
394       157.75    
4         1388      
400       157.75    
444       20160713  
459       93000546718000
461       7         
474       157.75    
5         M       
55        93000552181000
8         157.75    
854       n         
9         88929     
981       0         

index[1]
1021      0         
1584      89029     
16        1468416601.372
18        1468416601.372
22        89120     
3         1388      
361       0.71      
362       0.45     
388       n/a       
394       157.73    
4         1388      
400       n/a       
444       20160713  
459       93001362639104
461       26142     
474       157.749977558
5         IBM       
55        93001362849000
8         157.73    
854       p         
9         100       
981       0
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
index[0]
3         1388
4         1388
5         M
8         157.75
9         88929
16        1468416600.6006
18        1468416600.6006
22        89020
55        93000552181000
361       0.73
388       157.75
394       157.75
400       157.75
444       20160714
459       93000546718000
461       7
474       157.75
854       n
981       0
1021      1500
1584      88929

index[1]
3         1388 
4         1388 
5         M 
8         157.73 
9         100      
16        1468416601.372
18        1468416601.372
22        89120 
55        9300136284900 
361       0.71      
362       0.45  
394       157.73 
444       20160713  
459       93001362639104
461       26142     
474       157.749977558 
854       p   
981       0    
1021      0         
1584      89029          
388       n/a       
400       n/a
```

Comment: check this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450472/how-to-format-print-output-into-fixed-width

Comment: `print('{0: <10}{1: <10}'.format(k,v))`  will work in this case.

Comment: its not working. I actually need the key values in ascending order and the keys with n/a in the last.

Comment: File has only one row?

Comment: The above shown is just a sample expected output in which u will understand the format required. I tried sorting it using sort() but it shows "list has no attribute sort".

Comment: For me your code does not work (maybe python 3). I think the best is use small sample (5,6 items in file) and then add desired output. Because if file contains one data, your output another and desired else data, it is hard to find solution.

Comment: Can we get the output in order same as input file?

Comment: I think yes. What version of python use? `2` or `3`?

Comment: 2.7.5 python version

Comment: no file has multiple rows, the input is just a sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for creating `Series`, which is splited by `=` by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and converted to `DataFrame`. Then first column is casted to `int`, overwrite index by first column by `set_index` and [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
temp=u"""3=1388|4=1388|5=M|8=157.75|9=88929|1021=1500|854=n|388=157.75|394=157.75|474=157.75|1584=88929|444=20160713|459=93000546718000|461=7|55=93000552181000|22=89020|400=157.75|361=0.73|981=0|16=1468416600.6006|18=1468416600.6006|"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='|',index_col=None, header=None)
```

```
df1 = df.stack().str.split('=', expand=True)
df1.iloc[:,0] = df1.iloc[:,0].astype(int)
df1 = df1.set_index(0).sort_index()
print (df1)
                    1
0                    
3                1388
4                1388
5                   M
8              157.75
9               88929
16    1468416600.6006
18    1468416600.6006
22              89020
55     93000552181000
361              0.73
388            157.75
394            157.75
400            157.75
444          20160713
459    93000546718000
461                 7
474            157.75
854                 n
981                 0
1021             1500
1584            88929
```

Another solution with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df1= df.stack().str.split('=', expand=True)
df1.columns = ['a','b']
df1['a'] = df1['a'].astype(int)
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True).sort_values('a')
print (df1)
       a                b
0      3             1388
1      4             1388
2      5                M
3      8           157.75
4      9            88929
19    16  1468416600.6006
20    18  1468416600.6006
15    22            89020
14    55   93000552181000
17   361             0.73
7    388           157.75
8    394           157.75
16   400           157.75
11   444         20160713
12   459   93000546718000
13   461                7
9    474           157.75
6    854                n
18   981                0
5   1021             1500
10  1584            88929
```

Comment: its for only one row?