# Printing list of list element one per line

Tags: python

Lets say i have a list of list containing:

```
[[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'C']]
```

and i want to print it out as such:

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
```

I was thinking of using a for loop to print each element in the list of list but I wasn't quite sure of it.

```
lst = [[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'C']]
for i in lst:
    print(lst[i])    #perhaps needing to use \n in the loop?
```

Comment: did you try ? you may ..

Comment: different techniques mentioned here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450472/how-to-format-print-output-into-fixed-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack each nested list like this:

```
for num, let in lst:
    print(num, let)
```

What you're currently doing, with `for i in lst`, is printing each element in `lst`, while you seem to think the `for i in lst` syntax, accompanying the `lst[i]` indexing, is, well, indexing the list. That's not how that works.

If you wanted your desired output while iterating in this fashion, try this:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    print(' '.join(lst[i]))
```

More simply, you could do this:

```
for i in lst:
    print(' '.join(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for i in lst:
   print(i[0], i[1])
```

Comment: I presume op is using python 3+ based on their syntax so probably replicate that syntax?