# python and CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I want to save data in a csv file

I wrote this code

```
chemin = 'D:/Documents/prg5/'
NomFic= 'Datamat'
filepath = chemin + NomFic + '.csv'


file = open(filepath,"wb")
cw=csv.writer(file)

cw.writerow(("ALL"   "GP+G"   "GAMMA.PRIME"  "GP/G"))

for row in zip(choices0, PX, PA, C1*100):

    row = "%s %.2f %.2f %.2f" % row
    cw.writerow(row)            

file.close()
```

I would like to have my file with four columns with the same width
the first column is 'NI, 'Co', 'Ti'..
the others are numeric with two decimal

Comment: Then it is not really a CSV file right? Should you do it with csv writer then?

Comment: I can use a text file too

Comment: Then you might look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450472/how-to-format-print-output-into-fixed-width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use str.format() as in:

For the header:

```
with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write("{0:<3}{1:<10}{2:<10}{3:<10}\n".format("ALL", "GP+G", "GAMMA.PRIME", "GP/G"))
```

For the data:

```
with open(filename, "a") as file:
    file.write("{0:<3}{1:10.2f}{2:10.2f}{3:10.2f}\n".format(var0, var1, var2, var3))
```

In these examples, the fields are not comma separated.