# Leave empty spaces with format while printing an String in python

Tags: python, string, format

I have created a program.Here I need to leave some space and print an String after the spaces.I did that program with format in python.my code is below,

```
name = "myname"
print("{0:>10}".format(name))
#output="    myname"
```

Here, the sum of empty spaces and the length of name is equals to 10.I have declared the size inside print.
But I need to declare the size as a variable.I tried it like this,

```
num = 10
name = "myname"
print("{0:>num}".format(name))
```

but it did not worked.I need to know how I can fix this.I need to take the same output with giving the size with an variable.please help...

Comment: Didn't see it at first but this is extensively covered in the dupe, specifically in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41523601/9698684)

Comment: Does my answer help you? if so you can still tick answers

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
num_of_spaces = 10
name = "myname"
name.rjust(num_of_spaces)
```

Comment: This answer definitely produces the expected output. But since OP is already using string formatting, it's just a matter of adding another arg. (didn't downvote btw) See the dupe for more

Comment: @yatu IMHO one of the best things SO suggests is to learn different approaches to solve your problem. Since there was already a solution with string formatting, I wanted to share another way to tackle the OP's problem.

Comment: Sure no one denies that. Just saying OP might find a small tweak to his current solution more helpful. But sure, sharing different equally or improved approaches is always a good thing

Comment: Hmm, maybe the reason I mentioned? Couldn't tell

Comment: But the solution with string formatting was already posted (by you if I am not mistaken). Why not to add another solution? never mind...

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you as I've told you. IMO it's not good enough of a reason to downvote this. Wasn't me who did

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
num = 10
name ="myname"
print(" "*num,name)
```

Or you can also do it via:

```
name ="myname"
print('{0} {1}'.format(' '*num,name))
```

Comment: defining inside the print( )

Comment: I can't see how adding `print` qualifies as a change in approach. But, whatever